# Installing pgAdmin4 on CentOs - issue with conflicts

Tags: centos7, installation

I'm a newbie regarding configuration and all stuff related to servers. But I just want to install postgresql and pgAdmin4 on my server.

So installing postgresql went quite well without any issues. But unforutnately I faced an issue during installation of pgAdmin.

I did two steps from the start. So:

1. `yum -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/12/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`
2. `yum -y install pgadmin4`

First command works fine. But The second one throw an error like:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5 from install of libpq5-13.0-10PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgresql-libs-9.2.24-4.el7_8.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

There's my RepoList

```
repo id               repo name                                           status
base/7/x86_64         CentOS-7 - Base                                     10072
epel/x86_64           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64      13486
extras/7/x86_64       CentOS-7 - Extras                                     448
pgdg-common/7/x86_64  PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64     372
pgdg10/7/x86_64       PostgreSQL 10 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64              816
pgdg11/7/x86_64       PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64              872
pgdg12/7/x86_64       PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64              448
pgdg13/7/x86_64       PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64              172
pgdg95/7/x86_64       PostgreSQL 9.5 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64             726
pgdg96/7/x86_64       PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64             784
updates/7/x86_64      CentOS-7 - Updates                                    778
```

Thank you so much for your help!